# prolem with calc() in sass(CSS3)

Tags: sass

I'm trying to use the `calc()` function in a Sass stylesheet, but I'm having some issues. Here's my code:

```
$gutter-horizontal: 6rem;
    .col-1-of-2{
            width: calc((100% - #{$gutter-horizontal}) /2 );
        }
```

If I use the literal `54rem` instead of my `gutter-horizontal` variable, I get exactly what I want.
 
In Devtools it said invalid property value:

[image]

Where is the problem occurs? [Here](https://codepen.io/maishazaman7475/pen/BaNaPgw) is the `codepen(line 37)` in case you want to see where I stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have to put **a space** between the `+` or `-` operator in order for it to work properly. And you give unexpected whitespace before `)`

## fixed code:

```
width: calc((100% - #{$gutter-horizontal}) /2);
```

**From the MDN docs:**

> Note: The `+` and `-` operators must always be surrounded by whitespace.
>   The operand of `calc(50% -8px)` for instance will be parsed as a
>   percentage followed by a negative length, an invalid expression, while
>   the operand of `calc(50% - 8px)` is a percentage followed by a minus
>   sign and a length. Even further, `calc(8px + -50%)` is treated as a
>   length followed by a plus sign and a negative percentage. The `*` and `/`
>   operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is
>   allowed, and recommended.
>
> Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)